# Wiremock - how to match all permutations of array elements of a multipart/form-data in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, yaml, wiremock

I'm trying to mock a YAML API using JSON Wiremock for a PUT multipart/form-data. The multipart contains two arrays of metadata. How can I match a set of specific values (or regex) in each array, disregarding of the order.

We are bound to use YAML 2.0 (if you wonder), which is why we have these two arrays for the metadata. I've been able to successfully match specific values for the array (for example, for fileMetadataName, I can match "permissions,owner"), but I haven't found how to match the full set of potential values (5 values with all possible permutations, see YAML below).

Here is the JSON Wiremock file that can match one case of the array:

```
{
        "request": {
                "method": "PUT",
                "urlPath": "/files",
                "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": { "contains": "multipart/form-data"},
                        "Source": { "matches": "POC(.+)"}
                },
                "multipartPatterns": [
                        {
                                "headers": {
                                        "Content-Disposition": {
                                                "contains": "name=\"typeOfFile\""
                                        }
                                },
                                "bodyPatterns": [ {
                                        "matches": "PDF"
                                } ]
                        },
                        {
                                "headers": {
                                        "Content-Disposition": {
                                                "contains": "name=\"fileMetadataName\""
                                        }
                                },
                                "bodyPatterns": [ {
                                        "matches": "permissions,owner"
                                } ]
                        }
                ]
        },
        "response": {
                "status": 201,
                "jsonBody": {
                        "DocumentId": "123456789-123456789"
                }
        }
}
```

And here is an extract of the YAML that describes the multipart input:

```
paths:
  '/files':
    put:
      tags:
        - ProofOfConcept
      summary: Upload a file in the files repository
      description: Do the job
      operationId: putFile
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: Source
          description: ID of the sender
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
        - name: theFile
          description: The file to be uploaded
          in: formData
          required: true
          type: file
        - name: typeOfFile
          description: 'File type: PDF, JPG...'
          in: formData
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: fileMetadataName
          description: 'Metadata name. Possible values are: permissions, owner, group, creationDate, appGeneratedId (format: <app-name>;<id>)'
          in: formData
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        - name: fileMetadataValue
          description: Value associated to the corresponding metadata name
          in: formData
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Created
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/DocumentId'
```

I expect to be able to match for fileMetadataName, for example, all permutations of :

```
permissions, owner, group, creationDate, appGeneratedId
```

And in the case of fileMetadataValue, I expect to be able to match regex values for all permutations (e.g. ([0-9]{3,3}) for permissions).